# Problem with installing R packages in GraalVM

Tags: java, r, package, graalvm, fastr

I've installed graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0 on MacOS Catalina. I can run simple R code from java:

```
    Context context = Context.newBuilder("js").allowAllAccess(true).build();
    Context.newBuilder().allowNativeAccess(true).build();
    Set<String> languages = context.getEngine().getLanguages().keySet();
    System.out.println("Current Languages available in GraalVM: " + languages);
    context.eval("js","print('JavaScript: Hello World')");

    Context rcontext = Context.newBuilder("R")
            .allowAllAccess(true)
            .allowHostClassLoading(true)
            .allowIO(true)
            .allowNativeAccess(true)
            .allowCreateThread(true)
            .build();
    rcontext.eval("R", "print('R: Hello World');");
    int result = rcontext.eval("R", "sum").execute(new int[] {3,4,5}).asInt();
    System.out.println("result: " + result);
```

When I try to install almost any R library eg. Rcpp:

```
    source = Source.create("R", "install.packages(\"Rcpp\");");
    String text = rcontext.eval(source).asString();
```

I've got the following error:

> ```
> >  installing to
> > /Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/library/00LOCK-Rcpp/00new/Rcpp/libs
> >     ** R
> >     ** inst
> >     ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
> >     ** help
> >     *** installing help indices
> >     ** building package indices
> >     ** installing vignettes
> >     ** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
> ```

```
    com.oracle.truffle.r.runtime.ffi.DLL$DLLException: unable to load shared object '/Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/library/00LOCK-Rcpp/00new/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so'
      dlopen(/Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/library/00LOCK-Rcpp/00new/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so, 6): Symbol not found:
__ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev
      Referenced from: /Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/library/00LOCK-Rcpp/00new/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so
      Expected in: flat namespace
     in /Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/library/00LOCK-Rcpp/00new/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so
        at com.oracle.truffle.r.runtime.ffi.DLL$LoadPackageDLLNode.doLoad(DLL.java:704) ...

> 
>     at org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.eval(Context.java:345)
>       at com.oracle.truffle.r.launcher.REPL.lambda$readEvalPrint$1(REPL.java:124)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen(/Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/library/00LOCK-Rcpp/00new/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so,
> 6): Symbol not found:
> __ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev
>       Referenced from: /Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/library/00LOCK-Rcpp/00new/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so
>       Expected in: flat namespace
>      in /Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/library/00LOCK-Rcpp/00new/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so
>       at com.oracle.truffle.nfi.impl.NFIContext.loadLibrary(Native Method)
>       at com.oracle.truffle.nfi.impl.NFIContext.loadLibrary(NFIContext.java:170)
>       at com.oracle.truffle.nfi.impl.NFILanguageImpl$LoadLibraryNode.execute(NFILanguageImpl.java:147)
>       at org.graalvm.compiler.truffle.runtime.OptimizedCallTarget.callProxy(OptimizedCallTarget.java:474)
>       at org.graalvm.compiler.truffle.runtime.OptimizedCallTarget.callRoot(OptimizedCallTarget.java:449)
>       at org.graalvm.compiler.truffle.runtime.OptimizedCallTarget.callBoundary(OptimizedCallTarget.java:419)
>       at org.graalvm.compiler.truffle.runtime.OptimizedCallTarget.doInvoke(OptimizedCallTarget.java:403)
>       at org.graalvm.compiler.truffle.runtime.OptimizedCallTarget.callDirect(OptimizedCallTarget.java:349)
>       at org.graalvm.compiler.truffle.runtime.OptimizedDirectCallNode.call(OptimizedDirectCallNode.java:67)
>       at com.oracle.truffle.nfi.NFIRootNode.execute(NFIRootNode.java:106)
>       at org.graalvm.compiler.truffle.runtime.OptimizedCallTarget.callProxy(OptimizedCallTarget.java:474)
>       at org.graalvm.compiler.truffle.runtime.OptimizedCallTarget.callRoot(OptimizedCallTarget.java:449)
>       at org.graalvm.compiler.truffle.runtime.OptimizedCallTarget.callBoundary(OptimizedCallTarget.java:419)
>       at org.graalvm.compiler.truffle.runtime.OptimizedCallTarget.doInvoke(OptimizedCallTarget.java:403)
>       at org.graalvm.compiler.truffle.runtime.OptimizedCallTarget.callIndirect(OptimizedCallTarget.java:330)
>       at org.graalvm.compiler.truffle.runtime.OptimizedCallTarget.call(OptimizedCallTarget.java:320)
>       at com.oracle.truffle.r.ffi.impl.nfi.TruffleNFI_DLL.dlOpen(TruffleNFI_DLL.java:77)
>       at com.oracle.truffle.r.ffi.impl.nfi.TruffleNFI_DLL$TruffleNFI_DLOpenNode.execute(TruffleNFI_DLL.java:64)
```

> ```
>   at com.oracle.truffle.r.runtime.ffi.DLL$LoadPackageDLLNode.doLoad(DLL.java:699)
>   ... 509 more
> Caused by: Attached Guest Language Frames (0)
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Rcpp’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
>  unable to load shared object '/Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/library/00LOCK-Rcpp/00new/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so'
>   dlopen(/Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/library/00LOCK-Rcpp/00new/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so,
> ```
>
> > 6): Symbol not found:
> >     __ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev
> >           Referenced from: /Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/library/00LOCK-Rcpp/00new/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so
> >           Expected in: flat namespace
> >          in /Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/library/00LOCK-Rcpp/00new/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so
> >         Error: loading failed

On the same machine I have Rstudio where I can install any packages without problems.

This is the output of $GRAALVM_HOME/bin/R -e 'install.packages("Rcpp", type="source")':

```
install.packages("Rcpp", type="source")
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 3635277 bytes (3.5 MB)
* installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
** package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
/usr/local/bin/gcc-7 -I"/Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -O2 -DFASTR -DNO_GNUR   -fPIC  -O2  -DFASTR -DNO_GNUR  -c Date.cpp -o Date.o
/usr/local/bin/gcc-7 -I"/Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -O2 -DFASTR -DNO_GNUR   -fPIC  -O2  -DFASTR -DNO_GNUR  -c Module.cpp -o Module.o
/usr/local/bin/gcc-7 -I"/Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -O2 -DFASTR -DNO_GNUR   -fPIC  -O2  -DFASTR -DNO_GNUR  -c Rcpp_init.cpp -o Rcpp_init.o
/usr/local/bin/gcc-7 -I"/Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -O2 -DFASTR -DNO_GNUR   -fPIC  -O2  -DFASTR -DNO_GNUR  -c api.cpp -o api.o
/usr/local/bin/gcc-7 -I"/Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -O2 -DFASTR -DNO_GNUR   -fPIC  -O2  -DFASTR -DNO_GNUR  -c attributes.cpp -o attributes.o
/usr/local/bin/gcc-7 -I"/Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -O2 -DFASTR -DNO_GNUR   -fPIC  -O2  -DFASTR -DNO_GNUR  -c barrier.cpp -o barrier.o
/usr/local/bin/gcc-7 -Wl,-rpath,/Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/lib/,-rpath,/Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/../llvm/native/lib -L/Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/lib -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/../llvm/native/lib -lf2c -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -lR -Wl,-rpath,/Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/lib/,-rpath,/Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/../llvm/native/lib -L/Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/lib -L/Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/../llvm/native/lib -lf2c -o Rcpp.so Date.o Module.o Rcpp_init.o api.o attributes.o barrier.o
installing to /Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/library/00LOCK-Rcpp/00new/Rcpp/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
com.oracle.truffle.r.runtime.ffi.DLL$DLLException: unable to load shared object '/Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/library/00LOCK-Rcpp/00new/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so'
  dlopen(/Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/library/00LOCK-Rcpp/00new/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so, 6): Symbol not found: __ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev
  Referenced from: /Users/admin/tools/maszyny-jvm/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/library/00LOCK-Rcpp/00new/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like on MacOS Catalina the `type` argument of `install.packages` function does not default to `"source"`, which is essential for GraalVM R (aka FastR) -- binary packages built for GNU-R are not compatible with FastR. Try this:

```
install.packages("Rcpp", type="source")
```

If this does not work, also try installing the package from command line like so:

```
$GRAALVM_HOME/bin/R -e 'install.packages("Rcpp", type="source")'
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same error:            
  com.oracle.truffle.r.runtime.ffi.DLL$DLLException: unable to load shared object '.../graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/library/00LOCK-Rcpp/00new/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so'.  
     > sessionInfo().  
FastR version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Comment: If the package is indeed installed from sources, then there should be some C++ compiler invocations in the installation log. In the log you posted in your question, there are no such invocations. They should look like:

   ** using staged installation
   ** libs
   "some/path/R/bin/safe-forward-g++" -std=gnu++11 -I"some/path/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -O2 -DFASTR -DNO_GNUR   -fpic  -O2  -DFASTR -DNO_GNUR  -c api.cpp -o api.o
   ....more C++ compiler invocations...

Can you also provide the output of `otool -L $GRAALVM_HOME/jre/languages/R/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.dylib`?

Comment: I don't have Rcpp directory, it is removed after the error: * removing ‘graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/library/Rcpp’.  I checked: ./R/bin/configure_fastr
/usr/local/bin/brew
No Homebrew gcc 4.9 installation found.
Please ensure that you have gcc installed on your system using the homebrew command:
   brew install gcc@4.9   When I try to install it: Warning: gcc@4.9 4.9.4_2 is already installed and up-to-date

Comment: Ah, ok, in that case this sounds like this issue: https://github.com/oracle/fastr/issues/147 and it should be fixed in the next release 20.1.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Is it possible to fix my GraalVM setup in the current version?

Comment: I see the installation is actually using /usr/local/bin/gcc-7 as the compiler. Have you been changing the configuration in jre/languages/R/etc/Makeconf? The default configuration is available in jre/languages/R/etc/Makeconf.llvm and it should delegate to clang redistributed inside GraalVM (Labs LLVM Toolchain).

Comment: I didn't manually change files in R directory. I removed and reinstalled r component using gu. There are still /usr/local/bin/gcc-7 references in the install.packages() output.

Comment: Yes and that is weird, the default compiler as configured in jre/languages/R/etc/Makeconf should be clang distributed within GraalVM. Maybe something is interfering with that. Maybe you have `CC` or `CXX` or `LABS_TOOLCHAIN_CC` or similar variables in your environment?

Comment: I don't have variables with CC or CXX in my environment. To see current settings I added echo into Makeconf: CC is "graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/languages/llvm/native/bin/graalvm-native-clang"

Comment: graalvm-native-clang -v shows:  GraalVM wrapper script for clang
GraalVM version: 20.0.0. 
clang version 9.0.0 (GraalVM.org llvmorg-9.0.0-4-g9cf46c329d-bg2672c53415 9cf46c329d6c0640038501b17ed763a5acb5b23c)       
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
Thread model: posix   
InstalledDir: graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/lib/llvm/bin

Comment: Ok, that's good, but in the installation log you posted in your question, there's `gcc` not `graalvm-native-clang`, more specifically: `/usr/local/bin/gcc-7`